# About gdevelop saving and loading files

Tags: html, json, game-engine, 2d-games

I recently just started with this game engine Gdevelop and I’m having a hard time opening up games I created after saving it. Every time I try to open up the json it’s asking me to open it up on notepad, I’m just trying to view the game I created, and on the web as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A better practice is opening GDevelop first then cliking on **Files**,**Open** then choose json file of your game.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way but its not recommended because all the json files are affected, here are the steps:

right click game.json > Properties > Change... > Gdevelop

make sure to change it back if you don't want the default anymore in the future